# ¿Como editar elementos dentro de un div con su id?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo el siguiente código html

```
<div id="conferenceForm" class="column" style="padding: 30px;">
  <p id="questionConference"></p>
  <div id="optionsQuestions" class="ml-4 mb-4">
    <div class="form-check" style="display:none;" id="contentRadioButton0">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">question</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

Como puedo modificar los atributos del input y del label con java script que estan dentro del div con id="contentRadioButton0" con solo el id del div?

Por el momento solo puedo aditar el div con:

```
 var contentRadioButton = document.getElementById("contentRadioButton");
//contentRadioButton.style ...
```

Comment: Cual tiene el id contentRadioButton0?  El div o el buton?  Puede usar .children del div para obtener los controles adentro de sí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá te dejo un ejemplo de cómo modificar los atributos de los elementos internos:

```
// Se obtiene el div contenedor a través del ID
    var contentRadioButton = document.getElementById("contentRadioButton0");

    // Con el contenedor obtenido, se pueden obtener el input y label internos
    var inputElement = contentRadioButton.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    var labelElement = contentRadioButton.getElementsByTagName('label')[0];

    // Ejemplo, cambio de atributo en el label
    labelElement.innerHTML = 'prueba';
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono a la perfección la única duda a tu respuesta es... porque el [0] al hacer contentRadioButton.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];?

Comment: La función getElementsByTagName() te devuelve una colección de elementos (haz de cuenta que es como un array). Como en este caso, solo tienes un input y un label dentro del contenedor, te devuelve una colección con solo un elemento, entonces para acceder a dicho elemento se usa el [0], que es el primer índice de los arrays